# Error restoring a SQL Backup to a different SQL Server instance using SMO classes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

I am trying to use SMO objects in a C# console app to backup a 'source' SQL database on a 'source' server instance and then restore it under a different 'target' name on a different 'target' SQL server instance. The backup works fine, but the restore code throws this exception:

> Inner Exception 1:
>   ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL 
>   statement or batch.
>
> Inner Exception 2: SqlException: Cannot open backup device
>   'D:\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\mybackupRestore.bak'.
>   Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

**However, if I make the 'source' server and the 'target' server the same, then it all works perfectly.**

Please see below the `CopyDatabase` class and the calling code I am using.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem could be?

For information, I am using instances of SQL Server 2012.

```
   public static class CopyDatabase
{

    private static void ChangeFile(RelocateFile file, string oldDBName, string newDBName)
    {
        file.PhysicalFileName = file.PhysicalFileName.Replace(oldDBName, newDBName);
    }

    public static string Backup(string sourceServerName,
                            string sourceDatabaseName,
                            string deviceName)
    {
        var sourceServer = new Server(sourceServerName);

        string backupFileFullPath = Path.Combine(sourceServer.BackupDirectory, deviceName);

        Backup backup = new Backup
        {
            Action = BackupActionType.Database,
            Database = sourceDatabaseName,
            Incremental = false,
            CopyOnly = true,
            ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
        };

        backup.Devices.AddDevice(deviceName, DeviceType.File);

        backup.SqlBackup(sourceServer);

        return backupFileFullPath;
    }

    public static void Restore(string sourceServerName,
                               string sourceDatabaseName,
                                string targetServerName,
                                string targetDatabaseName,
                                string deviceName)
    {
        var sourceServer = new Server(sourceServerName);
        var targetServer = new Server(targetServerName);

        Restore restore = new Restore();

        restore.Devices.AddDevice(deviceName, DeviceType.File);

        RelocateFile dataFile = new RelocateFile
        {
            LogicalFileName = restore.ReadFileList(sourceServer).Rows[0][0].ToString(),
            PhysicalFileName = sourceServer.Databases[sourceDatabaseName].FileGroups[0].Files[0].FileName
        };

        ChangeFile(dataFile, sourceDatabaseName, targetDatabaseName);

        RelocateFile logFile = new RelocateFile
        {
            LogicalFileName = restore.ReadFileList(sourceServer).Rows[1][0].ToString(),
            PhysicalFileName = sourceServer.Databases[sourceDatabaseName].LogFiles[0].FileName
        };

        ChangeFile(logFile, sourceDatabaseName, targetDatabaseName);

        restore.RelocateFiles.Add(dataFile);
        restore.RelocateFiles.Add(logFile);

        restore.Database = targetDatabaseName;
        restore.NoRecovery = false;
        restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

        restore.SqlRestore(targetServer);
    }
```

Here is the calling code:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceServerName = "<SOURCE SERVER NAME HERE>";
        string sourceDatabaseName = "<SOURCE DB NAME HERE>";
        string targetServerName = "<TARGET SERVER NAME HERE>";
        string targetDatabaseName = "<TARGET DB NAME HERE>";
        string deviceName = "mybackup.bak";

        var backupFileFullPath = CopyDatabase.Backup(sourceServerName, sourceDatabaseName, deviceName);
        CopyDatabase.Restore(sourceServerName, sourceDatabaseName, targetServerName,targetDatabaseName, backupFileFullPath);

        Console.WriteLine("Done!");

    }
}
```

Comment: You may be running into a patthng issue. Can you try it using UNC filenames instead?

Comment: Hi @RossBush , I am not that familiar with SQL server unfortunately. Do you mean the UNC filenames for the *.bak file? Could you help me understand how would I get the UNC filenames? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that you are trying to restore from the D drive on a remote server, however, the way that code works, it will look for the bak filre on the Target or local instances D drive.

Comment: Hi @RossBush, I think I understand what you mean. But I don't know how to get the UNC path for the backup file. Can you assist please?

Comment: How are we to know what the UNC path to your server is...?

Comment: If you determine that this is the issue then you have a few options. The most straightforward option would be to "mapping a network drive".

Comment: @JacobH , you are not meant to know the UNC path. I am asking how I would find it out. That is, what steps I could take to get it.

Comment: Hi @RossBush, thanks for your reply. I am not sure this is the issue yet. Once I get the UNC path then I will be able to try it out.

Comment: @Cleve - Do a quick test first by manually placing the backup file locally. I would hate to lead you astray. I have never used the code above, however, my bet would be it is bad pathing.

Comment: Hi @RossBush, can I clarify, when you say 'placing the backup file locally' you mean on my local HDD right?

Comment: @Cleve - The local drive on the machine in which you are restoring to. I assume this is the same context your application is running from.

Comment: @RossBush, I am not restoring to a SQL instance on my PC. Both the source and target instances are remote servers. However, the app is running on my PC. Hope this makes sense?